# Is Repository pattern as same as Active Record pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, activerecord, repository-pattern

They seems to be similar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They are different.

**Active Record Pattern** defines An **object that wraps a row in a database** table or view, encapsulates the data access, and adds domain logic on that data.

**In the Repository pattern** all of the **data access is put in a separate class and is accessed via instance methods**. To me, just doing this is beneficial, since data access is now encapsulated in a separate class, leaving the business object to get on with business. This should stop the unfortunate mixing of data access and business logic you tend to get with Active Record.

Check this link for understanding:

http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/07/13/active-record-verses-repository/

Comment: Is it true to say that Repository pattern is alternative of Active Record pattern?

Comment: @afsharm No.... They are completely different, But ya they solve some of common problems :).

Comment: As an example of how both of them can coexist together is this arcticle. https://commandercoriander.net/blog/2014/10/02/isolating-active-record/

Comment: Inline with @StalkAlex, this answer should probably change since your answer is saying they're different. They different in the sense that they solve different problems, but not in the sense that they are different solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Active record pattern for persistance it's anti pattern for me, we have to seprate database access and treatement to another class for isolation, using the repository it's the best solution and simplified code source !

- repository pattern is goood
- active record pattern is bad (for database query)