# Implement ActiveRecord for Webservice client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, json.net

I'm writing a webservice client with C#/MVC 4 that communicates with a REST-Webservice, using JSON.net on the client side.
Everything is working fine so far, but I want to improve the architecture to make the handling more fluid.

I wrote a connector class and initialize it like this:

```
var conn = new MyConnector("admin", "admin", "http://localhost:9000");
```

Then I have a POCO class like this:

```
public class MyRecord
{
    [JsonProperty("record_id")]
    public string RecordId;
    ...
```

I'm saving changes by performing a PUT request to the Webservice. It looks like:

```
var updated = conn.UpdateRecord("MyRecordId", new  NameValueCollection{{"title","new_title"}});
```

What I want to do is to implement it more like ActiveRecord:

```
var myRecord = conn.GetRecord("myRecordId);
myRecord.title = "Foo";
myRecord.save();
```

That means that the MyRecord-class must be aware of the connection handler. That seems bad design to me, because MyRecord is basically a plain object. Another choice would be to pass the connection handler to the save-method, but that smells, too.

Any suggestions for improving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a "plain record" you should not implement the activerecord pattern. That is a contradiction. It sounds to me like you are more interested in the repository pattern.

As references have a look at:
[Is Repository pattern as same as Active Record pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486916/is-repository-pattern-as-same-as-active-record-pattern)

or for a broader perspective of your options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx

Comment: You're right - I'm using the Repository pattern for database access so far, but probably it's the best solution to extend it even to webservices. Thanks!